# Plotting geodataframe with holoviews

Tags: python, geodataframe, holoviews, geoviews

I have a geopandas data frame `combined_gdf` that consists of circular polygons like below.

```
fid Plot_name   Registered  Longitude   Latitude    geometry
0   130.0   2014-10-29  1   -51.460000  -1.740000   POLYGON ((-51.45910 -1.74000, -51.45914 -1.740...
1   131.0   2017-03-20  1   117.933300  5.166667    POLYGON ((117.93420 5.16667, 117.93416 5.16639...
2   2.0 210907  1   -83.459462  35.038255   POLYGON ((-83.45856 35.03825, -83.45861 35.037...
3   3.0 210910  1   -83.460817  35.037930   POLYGON ((-83.45992 35.03793, -83.45996 35.037...
4   4.0 1907185 1   -76.562554  38.891123   POLYGON ((-76.56165 38.89112, -76.56170 38.890...
```

I want to plot this with geoviews and holoviews. But no polygons were plotted.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import holoviews as hv
import geoviews as gv
import geoviews.tile_sources as gvts

#Setting a coordinate reference system
combined_gdf = combined_gdf.set_crs('epsg:4326')
print(combined_gdf.crs)

# Checking if there is invalid geometries

invalid_geometries = combined_gdf[~combined_gdf.geometry.is_valid]
print("Number of invalid geometries:", len(invalid_geometries))

# Define your plot using HoloViews and GeoViews
tiles = gvts.EsriImagery.opts(width=900, height=500)

# Use GeoViews to create the plot
polygons_plot = gv.Polygons(combined_gdf, vdims=['Plot_name']).opts(
    tools=['hover'], cmap='Category20',
    width=900, height=500, alpha=0.7,
    fontsize={'xticks': 10, 'yticks': 10, 'xlabel': 16, 'ylabel': 16},
    fill_color='yellow'
)

# Combine the tiles and polygons_plot
plot = tiles * polygons_plot

# Display the plot
plot
```

[image]